# Python call MS SQL 2019 procedures with multiple parameters

Tags: python

I am having a string size issue with python inserting into MS SQL 2019.

Variable to insert listed here

```
_ID = 'XXXYY770-009999',
_APName = 'LOB XX SALES AND REPORTING TOOLS',
_BID = '000111222',
_SID = '000333444',
_TID = '000555666',
_AskC = '2012-02-09T00:00:00.000Z',
Alias = 'AppsNAme (XXX YY),HEART,AppsNAme,YYY,OXW,SAR,DISTOXS,relovations ES DX',
description = 'APPNAME software is a BI tool that uses data input from data sources within company to provide critical business reporting for Sales and  guidelines mandated Compliance Reporting;This SQL set of applications supports the Sales and Compliance reporting for Industry and Partners Reporting Division.  It supplies the data for the AppName BI reporting tool;The App Data warehouse contains call center data for agents and customers as well as product and production data for the M&amp;R division.  Its used in compliance and sales reporting for the division'
```

MS SQL Procedure input parameters

```
Procedure dbo.AppProcess(
@_ID varchar(50),
@_APName varchar(255),
@_BID varchar(25),
@_SID varchar(25),
@_TID varchar(25),
@_AskC varchar(30),
@Alias varchar(255),
@Description varchar(1000)
```

Python insert script

```
def sqlInsert(_ID, _APName , _BID, _SID ,_TID ,_AskC ,Alias ,Description):
    conn_str = (
        r'DRIVER={SQL SERVER Native Client 11.0};'
        r'SERVER=SomeServer;'
        r'DATABASE=SomeDatabase;'
        r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    params = (_ID, _APName , _BID, _SID ,_TID ,_AskC ,Alias ,Description)
    sqlcmd = "Exec [EnviromentData].dbo.AskIdAppProcess @_ID = ?, @_APName = ?, @_BID = ?, @_SID = ?, @_TID = ?,@_AskC = ?, @Alias = ?,@Description = ?"
    cursor.setinputsizes([(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR,50,0),(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR,255,0),(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR,25,0),(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR,25,0),(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR,25,0),(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR,30,0),(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR,255,0),(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR,1000,0)])
    cursor.fast_executemany = True
    cursor.execute( sqlcmd, params )
    cnxn.commit()
    
    cursor.close()
    cnxn.close()
    return
```

Here is the called being made

```
sqlInsert(_ID,_APName,_BID,_SID,_TID,Alias,description,_AskC)
```

The script fails when trying to insert Alias and description. With error

```
DataError: ('22001', '[22001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Yet when I did len(Alias) = 66
and len(description)  = 558

Numbers may vary a little bit because I edited string due to privacy reasons but the size allocated to each string should be enough and fit. I there something wrong with the insert statement that causes failure?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to wrap my sql command inside 3 double quotes that was it.

```
sqlcmd = """Exec [EnviromentData].dbo.AskIdAppProcess @_ID = ?, @_APName = ?, @_BID = ?, @_SID = ?, @_TID = ?,@_AskC = ?, @Alias = ?,@Description = ?"""
```